# How can I "match" two different users and send the same value (a quiz app) on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a quiz app in android in which I use Firebase to register users and store questions. What I want to do is when users press a button , I want to send same question list to both of them and make them compete against one other. I have little to no idea on how to achieve this.

What I think is the following. When a user clicks find me a match, I will add him to a table (lets name it *waitingMatch*), and if there is someone who is close to him (region wise) I will remove them from that table and add the pair to a new table (lets name it *VERSUS*). Is it a feasible approach or is there a better way to match users?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I think the root document should look in firebase

```
+ /
  + Sessions: [
     + *
       + members: [
         + * 
           + uid: "xx"
         + * 
           + uid: "xxx"
  + Users : [
     + *
       + uid: "xxx"
       + username: "name"
       + bio: "description"
     + *
       + uid: "xx"
       + username: "name2"
       + bio: "description" ]
```

I think its best to use Firebase-Authentication for authenticating the users, and simply store their uid in the database

the session root can additionally contain extra information, for example, about who won etc.

Comment: I am upvoting the answer since this is useful, but I will wait before accepting it to see other answers that can be more useful. I already use firebase-authentication, I am an experienced MySQL user but I am not familiar with firebase. Should I switch into MySQL in firebase

Comment: Firebase is a NoSQL database, and SQL normalization rules may/may not still apply. Sometime its better to leave your data set normalized up to the 2NF state, and not go all the way up to 3NF. When deciding the data structure for your app, its better to look at the views and model the data after that.